# Spring MVC <form:form> и CommandName

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю принцип работы в Spring MVC.
 1. Когда я создаю форму  и потом принимаю её в контроллере, я получаю готовый объект моего класса (те, в отличии от сервлетов, мне не нужно брать каждый атрибут и подставлять его в объект)? Верно ли я понял принцип работы?
 2. В чём различие между modelAttribute и commandName?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Да, верно, это называется *data binding*. Spring извлекает данные из запроса и предоставляет вам готовый объект. Причем использование TLD библиотеки Spring (это та которая предоставляет вам тэги `form:*`) не требуется - она просто предлагает более удобный способ записи при передачи объекта во View. Можете писать формы на голом HTML и `@ModelAttribute` будет работать точно также.
2. Ничем, *сommandName* устарело, но видимо сохраняется для обратной совместимости Если [посмотреть код](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/FormTag.java), это один и тот же объект

---

```
/**
 * Set the name of the form attribute in the model.
 * <p>May be a runtime expression.
 * @see #setModelAttribute
 */
public void setCommandName(String commandName) {
    this.modelAttribute = commandName;
}

/**
 * Get the name of the form attribute in the model.
 * @see #getModelAttribute
 */
protected String getCommandName() {
    return this.modelAttribute;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, те лучше использовать modelAttribute? Не могли бы вы написать пример кода, когда идёт обработка на чистом html и передаётся объект? (Не очень понимаю, как он его соберёт)

Comment: Чтобы разобраться кто во что собирает попробуйте сделать следующее: создайте тестовую JSP страничку, где будет использоваться Spring Form тэги (о которых вы спрашивали); запустите проект, зайдите на эту страничку и посмотрите ее исходный код в браузере (вы увидите в какой HTML код Spring отобразил форму, это называется рендеринг); подтвердите форму и в консоли браузера посмотрите запрос, который отправляется на сервер и обратите внимание на имена параметров - они колжны быть такими же как имена полей в классе помеченным `@ModelAttribute@`

Comment: Те реально без особых усилий не используя библиотеку спринга на jsp, отправлять объект?

Comment: Конечно, ведь в результате все эти вспомогательные тэги `form:*` все равно преобразуются в HTML. Точно такой же HTML код можно сразу написать в JSP и без использования тэгов Spring. Эта библиотека просто вспомогательная вещь чтобы писать меньше кода. Кому-то нравится, кому-то нет.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно. 
`commandName` указывает отправляемый в контроллер объект. 
но если указать в атрибуте формы вместо `commandName` - `modelAttribute` (лично у меня) вылетает исключения (но скорее это связано с версией спринга).
Кроме этого, в одной из последних версий релиза спринга, совсем недавно узнал, можно больше не реализовать отдельные классы (пример: `Class` - `ClassForm`), которые обычно помещались в отдельные пакеты, а в самом контролере создавать метод, в котором мы просто возвращаемый заполняемое ентити:

```
@ModelAttribute(name="entity")
public Entity getEntity() {
   return new Entity();  
} 


@RequestMapping({value})
public String someMethod(@ModelAtrribute("entity") Entity entity) {}
```

Спринг на jsp определяет имя указанное в параметре аннотации как `commandName`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ :)